# Why Mysql Query Count is different?

Tags: mysql

I have a Customer table, my client want to not physically delete any record from this table so I use a TINYINT field "IsDeleted" to keep track of deleted customers.

Now i m in a situation where i need to exclude Deleted Customers but when i tired following Query it gives me less number of records

```
select count(*) from customer where IsDeleted <> 1; (Count = 1477)
```

then the following

```
select count(*) from customer where (IsDeleted = 0 or IsDeleted is  null); (Count = 1552)
```

why the above query counts are different?
why "NULL" value is not counted in " IsDeleted <> 1" check?

Please suggest.

Comment: First try to group results by IsDeleted and see what different values do you have for isDeleted

Comment: Change the query in the right panel so you can see the difference between using int and varchar column types.  http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7bf0a/5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Duniyadnd and triclosan point out this is caused by the column type for IsDeleted.
Change the query in the right panel so you can see the difference between using int and varchar column types. sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7bf0a/5

Comment: Glad to help. BTW this is how you could alter it. "UPDATE customer SET IsDeleted = 0 WHERE IsDeleted IS null;" 

sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cc9f1/1/0

Answer (score 0):

You cannot correct use comparing operations for NULL-values. Consider to change type of `IsDeleted` to `enum('N','Y')` with Not NULL option.

Answer (score 0):

Null is not an int. As soon as you did <> 1, that means it would only look at ints. Null ideally means something that does not exist (that's why a lot of people use it instead of 0 in case you do store 0s in the table).

If you only have null, 0 and 1 values in the `isDeleted` column, you would probably find a difference between the two queries (1522-1477) to be the total number of nulls in your table (75).